# Why can't C++ using-declaration expose a protected member of base as a public member of derived?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, standards, using-declaration

As per [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

> Using-declaration introduces a member of a base class into the derived
> class definition, such as to expose a protected member of base as
> public member of derived.

However, the following code can't compile:

```
class A {
protected:
    A(int, int) {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A;
};

int main() {
    B(1, 2); // error: calling a protected constructor of class 'A'
}
```

**Why can't C++ using-declaration expose a protected member of base as a public member of derived as expected?**

Comment: from the link you posted `If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored.`

Comment: Or if you want more authoritative reference, [namespace.udecl#16](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#16) explains this. Added in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note on the same page the section on [inheriting constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#%20Inheriting_constructors) states:

> If overload resolution selects an inherited constructor, **it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class: the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored.**

(emphasis mine)

Note the emphasized part *"the accessibility of the using-declaration that introduced it is ignored"*. And since the base class constructor `A::A(int, int)` is `protected`(meaning it is **inaccessible inside** `main`), we get the mentioned error.

---

The same can be seen from [namespace.udecl#16](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#16):

> A using-declaration has the usual accessibility for a member-declaration. **Base-class constructors considered because of a using-declarator are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the base class; the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored.**